# Tomcat -8.0.36 Moving from Old domain to new domain by keeping same ip- Re-write valve does not work

Tags: tomcat

I have a web app which is deployed on Tomcat. I am updating server for same IP domain name. Earlier it was `abc.oldodmain.com`, now it is `abc.newdomain.com`. I want to set up a redirect; if a user hits `abc.olddomain.com` it should be re-directed to `https://abc.newdomain.com`. I am using Rewrite Valve for Tomcat 8.0.36. With this valve I am getting too many re-directs.

`Rewrite.config` is set to following

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://abc.newdomain.com/$1 [R]
```

I would like to set up SSL for both URLs as well. Right now I am using `localhost` in my hostname config and only one SSL is active at a time. The old SSL shows violated, please let me know how can I add two certs for different URLs although I am using the same `war` file.

Comment: You should only ask one question in one post so that a single answer can be compared to other answers and selected as the most correct one.

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question; but please accept the suggested edit I submitted just now.

Answer (score 1):

Create virtual host for both the domains provide rewrite in the old domain virtual host.then map the webapp files to new domain. Hope it helps.